# Selecting the value of a column not in GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I need a query that selects a column value that the data is not grouped by. I must group by Vkn number to get the Sum of InvoiceCount, but I want to select FirmName without grouping by it.

```
public Model1
{
    public int VKN {get; set;}
    public string FirmName {get; set;}
    public string {get; set;}
    public string InvoiceCount {get; set;}
}

List<Model1> temp = new List<Model1> { /*adding some value... */ };

var temp = from m in temp group by new { row.VKN, row.FirmName} into g
           select new { FirmName = g.Key.FirName,
                        VKN = g.Key.Vkn,
                        InvoiceCountSum = g.Sum(x => x.InvoiceCount),
                      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `row.VKN` and use almost any aggregate function to get other fields that not participated in grouping, but only if you care which result from grouped collection like that (e.g. you definitely know `FirmName` is unique per `VKN`):

```
FirmName = g.Min(x => x.FirmName)
```

Comment: this code work true. Thanks. Is there any other  way to do it ?

Comment: @user990513 well there are a lot of different ways in programming to achieve same result. But I need to know what exactly you need. For example you can use **Aggregate** instead of **Sum** to make a comma separated string with all FirName.